# Converting javascript string to object method and calling it?

Tags: javascript

I've come across some code which allows you to convert a string of a function name to a function and use it:

```
var strFun = "someFunction";
var strParam = "this is the parameter";

//Create the function
var fn = window[strFun];

//Call the function
fn(strParam);
```

I was wondering if there was a way to do the same for object methods, e.g.:

```
var fn = window["onclick"];
var body = document.body;
body.onclick = function() {
    alert('yo');
}
// This won't work [Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLBodyElement> has no method 'fn']
body.fn(); // expecting body.onclick(); via substitution of fn with a onclick function
```

Comment: whoops I was thinking abstractly, I forgot that that was valid javascript code, I reupdated what I was try to say.

Comment: @Derek: your code still doesn't make sense. You're creating one thing, and calling another.

Comment: Once again, if you want to attach click handlers, you don't need all that. Use `addEventListener`.

Comment: I'm going after the abstract meaning of the code so body.fn() == body.onclick()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
var body = document.body;
body.onclick = function() {
    alert('yo');
}

var strfun = 'onclick';
var fn = body[strfun];
fn();
```

To call the onclick function of the body.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call the function in the context of your object:

```
fn.call(your object);
```